# BackgroundWorker and access to global variable

Tags: c#, serial-port, c#-2.0, backgroundworker

I got global variable SerialPort comm; After opening com port im reading recived bytes and i get exception that com port is closed..
How can i access to it in backgroundworker correctly?
 are there better way to declare comm?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    while(true)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string str = comm.ReadLine();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** yea ... just use this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx 
 no need for BackgroundWorker

Comment: This is the example from the MSDN, I always laugh when see this `if((worker.CancellationPending == true))`, should be `if(worker.CancellationPending == true)`

Comment: I don't see any global variable in the code you have included, need to add it so we can see exactly what type it is.

Comment: Have you tried with setting DataReceived EventHandler. You can read the serial port in the UI thread. Unless of course it influences your UI significantly.

Comment: It's not a problem to use the com from BGworker, just add a lock() if you intend to write to a globally shared buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SerialPort.ReadLine() is a blocking call.  It won't return until the port has received a line of text and a NewLine.  Which inevitably means that your test for CancellationPending will not work, the code is stuck in the ReadLine() call.  So you'll call the bgw's CancelAsync() call and then close the serial port.  And that causes the ReadLine() method to throw an exception.

There are no good ways to do this cleanly, you don't have any other way to force the ReadLine() method to return.  So catch the exception, check if CancellationPending is true and bail out when it is.

Comment: currently timeouts are set to -1.
i'm first time using backgroundworker so i don't know what should i really do. i just want to read received bytes and put them in table as HEX and ASCII